# How can I create a barcode without text on barcodesinc.com?

Tags: barcode

I'm trying to create a barcode on barcodesinc.com's [Free Online Barcode Generator](http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php). Under advanced options, I see that there is a checkbox for "Draw Value Text", when I uncheck it and regenerate the barcode, though, it is still checked.

When you generate a barcode, e.g.:
[image]

It uses a URL such as the following:

```
http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=123456&style=197&type=C39&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=3
```

When I change the other comboboxes, I notice that the parameter that is changing is `style`. It stands to reason that I can send a style value which will not include the text underneath the barcode. The question is which style value do I need to use?

```
style     border     text     stretch     negative
-----     ------     ----     -------     --------
???       no         no       no          no
197       yes        yes      no          no
709       yes        yes      no          yes
453       yes        yes      yes         no
965       yes        yes      yes         yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style with everything set to `no` is `68`. I found this out by noticing that it says "Powered by [Barcode](http://www.mribti.com/barcode/home.php)", and then I tried the [sample generator](http://www.mribti.com/barcode/sample.php) on that site, and examined the `style` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tested all the styles from 1 to 999 :

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 999; $i++ )
        ▼                                                               ▼
 echo "$i<img src='http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=$i" .
                  "&style=$i&type=C128B&width=300&height=65&xres=1&font=1'>" .
      "<br/>";             ▲
```

This code allows to see all the possibilities : many styles won't work, other styles will give you frame and no text (aligned to the left, center or right), others will give your frame an text, etc.